# Как исправить предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

*Он полностью копировал его — жесты, мимика, даже шутил так, что никто не заподозрил подмены.* В этом предложении, по-моему, есть какая-то корявость, неправильность. Здесь проблемы с синтаксисом? Или я неправ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По смыслу, "никто не заподозрил подмены"  должно относится к "копировал" , а по синтаксису относится к "шутил". Поэтому предлагаю такой вариант: "Он полностью копировал его жесты, мимику и даже манеру шутить, так что никто не заподозрил подмены."

Answer (score 2):

Прав. Следует просклонять слово *мимика* (его жесты и мимику), и корявость как рукой снимет.